# Example of a topology that requires infinite unions

Tags: general-topology

The standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ has the property that any open set $U$ can be written as the countable union of open intervals, which are basis elements for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, I believe, in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, one may replace the axiom of topology that "the union of arbitrarily many open sets is open" with the alternative axiom that "the countable union of open sets is open.''

Are there examples of a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ where this axiom replacement is **not** possible.  That is, is there a topology $\mathscr{T}$ with basis $\mathscr{B}$ and open set $U\in\mathscr{T}$ such that

$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i \neq U$$

for any choice of $B_i$ in $\mathscr{B}$?

Comment: Discrete topology on an uncountable set.

Comment: I don’t follow why this would allow you to replace the axiom. Why does the ability to write an open set as a countable union help you with concluding an arbitrary union is open?

Comment: Hi rschwieb.  In $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology, every set that can be written as an arbitrary union of open sets can also be written as a countable union of open sets. So, if one replaced the axiom of arbitrary unions with the weaker axiom of countable unions, the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ does not change, and one could prove that arbitrary unions of open sets are open as a theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed point topology on $\Bbb R$ where an open set is defined as empty or a set that contains the fixed point $x_0\in\Bbb R$. We take the basis $B=\{\{x_0,y\}:y\in\Bbb R\}$. Then any uncountable set containing $x_0$ can't be written as a countable union of basis elements.

Note also that for the same topology, we might get different results for different bases. If we take the basis as the topology itself, "axiom replacement" is always possible.